# Nested menu stop triggering not directly clicked <li>s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have built an expandable, nested menu in `<ul> <li> <ul> <li>` style in HTML. Both, the upper and lower `<li>`s have an `onCLick` attribute. when clicking on the lower (nested) li, the upper li should not trigger `onClick` or at least submit to the handler, that it was activated indirectly.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please show the code you have tried, then I can help.

Comment: event.stopPropagation() will do the stuff..

Comment: Thanks, I will try event.stopPropagation()  right now. My code has the style of http://htmldog.com/techniques/dropdowns/ this tutorial, with for example "Mammals" and "Echidnas" both having an onClick attribute, and when Echidnas is clicked, Mammals' onCLick-Handler gets triggered too.

Comment: Could you please show your code? What did you try?

Comment: Anoop Joshis answer was correct, I stopped propagating the entire div with the nested elements on document being ready. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".header").click(function(){
        $(this).children(".children").toggle();
    });
   $(".header a").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
   });
});
```

If it dont: Send me a message